# Ошибка при повторном запуске

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте.

Вот этот кусок кода (дан ниже) при повторном запуске программы выдает ошибку:

> terminate called after throwing an
> instance of 'std::ios_base::failure'
> what(): basic_ios::clear

Я так понимаю, нужно очистить буфер ошибок, что я и делаю: `content.clear(); pageHead.clear();`, но тем не менее ошибка все равно остаётся. Это моя первая программа, так что готов к любой критике. Собирается под виндой minGW32, curl+ssl+zlib также собран под виндой. Все библиотеки и заголовки закинуты в папку MinGW, в общем, все вроде бы как нужно.
Это кусок кода, в котором проблема (элемент данные и функция мейн с вызовом я упустил,  так как несущественно):

```
curl_handle = curl_easy_init();

        // задаем адрес страницы
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, url_prime.c_str() );

        content.clear(); //предварительная очистка переменной-буфера
        //  сохраняем html код cтраницы в строку content
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,     &content);

        pageHead.clear(); //предварительная очистка переменной-буфера
        // Загловок ответа сервера выводим в pageHead
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, write_head);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER,    &pageHead);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,1);// автоматически заполняет поле referer

        // разрешаем авто перенаправление
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        // max 5-ть перенаправлений
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
        // разрешаем использовать куки
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,"");

        //Выполняет отправку запроса на сервер и возвращает CURLE_OK в случае успеха, в противном случае код ошибки
        resData = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);

        if (resData != CURLE_OK)
        {
            printf( "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(resData) );
            resData = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
        }
```

Есть подозрение, что ошибка связанна с функцией записи в буфер.
На просторах Интернета искал разные варианты реализации этой функции, но все, что нашел, также вылетает с ошибкой при повторном запуске.

```
 static size_t write_data(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, std::string* data)
{
    if (data)
     {
         data->append(ptr, size*nmemb);
         return size*nmemb;
     }
    else return 0;  // будет ошибка
}
```

Comment: Отладчиком пробовали определить место возникновения проблемы?

Comment: "повторный запуск" - это в смысле, что программа отработала, завершила свою работу (пропала с списка процессов), а потом снова ее запускаете?